# Jasper report and hibernate annotations

Tags: java, hibernate, jasper-reports

I'm Using Hibernate with an H2 database, I'm using annotations for mapping Object with Relational tables instead of hbm.xml file. I want to integrate jasper report with out changing hibernate configuration.In jasper report studio, i choose hibernate session to connect to my H2 database, i have provided the hibernate.cfg.xml.After clicking test i got this error:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at net.sf.jasperreports.data.hibernate.HibernateDataAdapterService.contributeParameters(HibernateDataAdapterService.java:129)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.data.AbstractDataAdapterService.test(AbstractDataAdapterService.java:105)
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.data.DataAdapterEditorPart$1.widgetSelected(DataAdapterEditorPart.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4180)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3769)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1018)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:694)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.rcp.intro.Application.start(Application.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.data.hibernate.HibernateDataAdapterService.contributeParameters(HibernateDataAdapterService.java:85)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: An AnnotationConfiguration instance is required to use <mapping class="bean.Entreprise"/>
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:1648)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1603)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1582)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1556)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1510)
    ... 34 more
```

After that i go in other way by choosing an empty datasource, create field manually in jasper report studio, but again i get a problem (Fields need to have custom type whitch i use in my project like entreprise, transaction ..etc.
So how i can tell jasper report to use my own types.

And then i provide jasper report with collection of database in my java code: like so:

```
try {
            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("./report/transactionReprot.jrxml");

            JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(inputStream);

            JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
            HashMap parameter = new HashMap();

            JRBeanCollectionDataSource beanDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(transactionModel.getTransactionList());
            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameter, beanDataSource);

            if (jasperPrint != null) {
                JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint);
                System.out.println("Printed");
            } else
                System.out.println("Not able to print");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JRException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

So my question is: How to integrate JasperReports in project that uses hibernate with annotations?

If JasperReports can't work with annotations, so what other solution for this problem?